# $ne not working in mongodb stitch

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to do a not equal operation (`$ne`) in mongodb stitch. running the query in the debug console returns the entire data set.

sample data:

```
{"name": "first", "lastname": "last"},
{"name": "second_first","lastname": "second_last"}
```

when attempting to find any of the string values with `$ne`:

```
{
 "database": "<DBname>",  
 "collection": "<collectionname>",  
 "query": { "lastname": { "$ne": "second_last" } }
}
```

returns the entire document, while:

```
{
 "database": "<DBname>",
 "collection": "<collectionname>",
 "query": { "lastname":{ "$eq": "second_last" } }
}
```

does return the second document only.

running the exact same `$ne` query above in Mongodb compass connected to the same cloud instance does output the correct results.

Comment: There is nothing wrong in your query. May be you should share how you connect to stitch

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I am running the query inside stitch and not connecting to it from any external api. I am using the debug console on stitch which runs queries against the data directly on the server.

It is worth mentioning that running the pipeline in two separate stages: 1) getting all data from the collection without any query. 2) a match stage that does the %ne operation works. but I am not able to run a count stage afterwards as there is no built in aggregate stage.

Comment: Did you get a solution for this? it's still not functioning correctly in stitch

Comment: I have the same issue, on Stitch manual they say `$ne` is supported:
https://docs.mongodb.com/stitch/mongodb/mongodb-service-limitations/#query-operators

Then I found this post, where another guy has issues:
https://mongodb.canny.io/mongodb-stitch/p/fix-nin-and-ne-operators